# How to show this integral operator is hemicontinuous?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, continuity, sobolev-spaces, nonlinear-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a bounded domain.
Let $a \in B C\left(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}_{s y m}^{n \times n}\right)$ with
$$
a(u) \xi \cdot \xi \geq \underline{\alpha}|\xi|^{2}, \quad \xi \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \quad u \in \mathbb{R}
$$
for some $\underline{\alpha}>0$. Then, the operator
$$
A: \stackrel{\circ}{H}^{1}(\Omega) \rightarrow H^{-1}(\Omega):=\left(\stackrel{\circ}{H}^{1}(\Omega)\right)^{\prime}
$$
given by
$$
\langle A u, \phi\rangle_{\dot{H}^{1}(\Omega)}:=\int_{\Omega} a(u) \nabla u \cdot \nabla \phi \mathrm{d} x, \quad u, \phi \in \stackrel{\circ}{H}^{1}(\Omega),
$$
is hemicontinuous .

I know there may be different definitions of hemicontinuous. The one I am using is: a mapping is hemicontinuous if the mapping $t\to \langle A+tv, \phi\rangle$ is a $C[0,1]$ mapping. Here $u, v$ are also elements of $\stackrel{\circ}{H}^{1}(\Omega)$.

So I guess we just use the definition and show sequential continuity. Assume $t_n \to t$. then we want $$
\langle A (u+t_nv), \phi\rangle_{\dot{H}^{1}(\Omega)}:=\int_{\Omega} a(u+t_nv) \nabla u \cdot \nabla \phi \mathrm{d} x 
$$ to converge to $$
\langle A (u+tv), \phi\rangle_{\dot{H}^{1}(\Omega)}:=\int_{\Omega} a(u+tv) \nabla u \cdot \nabla \phi \mathrm{d} x 
$$

Well, I'm not sure how we deal with the right hand side now...